# How do i get data from an SQLITE database to an array in android?

Tags: android, arrays, database, sqlite, android-cursor

Pretty sure this is an easy one, but i'm getting confused by all the examples that adapt the data returned from a cursor into different views. **I just want to run a rawquery and put each item of data returned into a float array** (so that i can add them up later). What do i need to use for this? *Thanks*

Comment: Have you forgotten to initialize the budgetInArray (presumably you want to do that just after the "numRows = incomeCursor.getCount()" line)?

Comment: Yes that was exactly the problem, just got there myself -_- Thanks for pointing it out too :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll still have a cursor when you query your database, but once you got the cursor you could iterate over it, pulling out the values you need into an array, like this:

```
DbAdapter db = new DbAdapter(mContext);
    int columnIndex = 3; // Whichever column your float is in.
    db.open();
    Cursor cursor = db.getAllMyFloats();
    float[] myFloats = new float[cursor.getCount()-1];

    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {                       
        for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++)
        {
            myFloats[i] = cursor.getFloat(columnIndex);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }           
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // Do what you want with myFloats[].
```

Comment: ahhh wicked thank you very much! The only thing i don't understand is the need to use columnIndex? I suppose i'll find out if i look into the method. I assume the actual rawQuery is done in getAllMyFloats right? Cheers this really helped.

Comment: oh also one other thing, do the columns start at an index of 0 or 1?

Comment: If you have a table with several columns, then you'll need the column index to get the specific data field you're looking for. Columns are zero-indexed.

Answer (score 3):

Don't minus by 1 in `float[] myFloats = new float[cursor.getCount()-1];` because (int i =0) or i start from 0. If you use it, will appear `Java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`. You need array index until `[cursor.getCount()]`, not until `[cursor.getCount()-1]`. So the correct thing is `float[] myFloats = new float[cursor.getCount()];`