# fetching data from sqlite into array in android

Tags: android, sqlite

The code to  returns all the data in the table in list.But this isn't working.
I've called this method from CheckData class which is called by main class

```
public List<String[]> selectAll() {
        List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        Cursor cursor = db
                .query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        int x = 0;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String[] b1 = new String[] { cursor.getString(1),
                        cursor.getString(2) };
                list.add(b1);
                x = x + 1;
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return list;
    }
```

My database contains 3 columns - id(integer primary key), symbol(text) and company_name(text).

My Data Base name is AppDB and table name is scrip.

Comment: What is it that isn't working? What do you see?

Comment: First Explain what you want to ask...

Comment: @zmbq - When I run the app, first i see a button then i click on it.

Comment: it should display all data from database, but instead it shows that application has stopped working.

Comment: MY BASIC PURPOSE IS TO DISPLAY DATA ON ANDROID EMULATOR WHICH IS STORED IN AN ALREADY CREATED SQLITE DATABASE.

WHAT CAN I DO?

Comment: Where are you connecting with Database???How you are Querying?did you have debug it?See how to connect SQLLite and query it

Comment: Please put a try catch block and share the exception. Its impossible to guess what is really happpening

Comment: I'm doing the connectivity by using DataManipulator class which includes static class OpenHelper which extends SQLOpenHelper.
It contains constructor,onCreate,onUpgrade methods.

As far as fetching is concerned, it is done by using rawQuery method as shown in above code.

Comment: what does 

"com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: device not found"
means?

Comment: Last few lines from my LogCat - 

com.android.providers.downloads/.DownloadProvider: pid=435 uid=10001 gids={1015, 1023, 1024, 1006, 2001, 3003, 3007}
11-24 10:23:54.779: D/PackageManager(89): generateServicesMap(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator): 2 services unchanged
11-24 10:23:54.800: I/ActivityManager(89): Start proc com.android.mms for broadcast com.android.mms/.transaction.MmsSystemEventReceiver: pid=442 uid=10016 gids={3003, 1015}
 D/ConnectivityService(89): ConnectivityChange for mobile: DISCONNECTED/DISCONNECTED
 D/ConnectivityService(89): Attempting to switch to wifi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the good tutorial to **LEARN** use of Android-SQLite.
so,I also advise you the same As I answered **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152006/how-to-fetch-data-from-sqlite-table-and-display-it-in-textview-in-android/8152097#8152097)**

Comment: But all these tutorials shows demo in which we create database and table during coding.
I already have the database. I have to fetch the data.

Comment: buddy, it's not like that.
The thing is after modifying the code so that it displays the data from existing database, it doesn't work.

Comment: Now code contains 
(1) list.get(x);
     Log.e("selectAll method Error", b1[x]);
     x = x + 1;

and(2)
   Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
     "select symbol,company_name from Scrip", new String[] {
       "symbol", "company_name" });

Comment: i just seen one another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842520/how-do-i-get-data-from-an-sqlite-database-to-an-array-in-android just check